# Unable to write multiple simultaneous filesinks from appsrc

Tags: python, multiprocessing, gstreamer, python-gstreamer

I'm having trouble saving from appsrc to filesink when I have multiple gstreamer processes running simultaneously. Only one of the gstreamer processes will write correctly  while the others will all write nearly empty files. There appears to be write contention during the filesink operation.

Note: I am using gstreamer1.0 (v1.8.2) with python3 (v3.5.2) on MAC OS 10.11.6.

Here's what my code is actually doing:

In the background, I am reading in frames from a single video stream, converting each frame to BGR numpy arrays of size 1920x800x3, and storing each frame in a circular buffer. I have built a "gstreamer_writer function" that reads frames from this circular buffer, converts the frames into a byte stream, and feeds this stream into appsrc.

This works by instantiating a new multiprocess (multiprocessing.Process) and pointing this at the "gstreamer_writer function". This works completely fine for a single multiprocess/function call.  Appsrc is correctly fed the byte stream and I save these BGR frames into a mp4 with h264 encoding using the following gstreamer pipeline:

```
appsrc format=3 name=app emit-signals=true do-timestamp=true is-live=true blocksize=4608000 max-bytes=0 caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=800 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=1920,height=800 ! vtenc_h264 ! mp4mux ! filesink location=test1.mp4
```

However, if I instantiate two or more multiprocesses and point them at the function only one of filesinks will work properly. For example, if one is writing to "test1.mp4" and the other is writing to "test2.mp4" then one of the videos will be written correctly and the other will fail and write a nearly empty mp4 (~500kb). It's not always the same mp4, 50% of the time test1.mp4 gets written correctly and 50% of the time test2.mp4 gets written correctly. It looks like there is some kind of race condition or write contention that is preventing both mp4s from being written to file properly.

One thing to note is that each multiprocess is accessing the same frames from the same ring buffer. I thought this may have been causing problems with gstreamer. However, if I display the streams with autovideosink instead of writing them to file, I can display as many streams/multiprocesses as I'd like. This means the data is being properly passed through the pipeline and is only failing during the write stage. I tested this using the gstreamer command:

```
appsrc format=3 name=app emit-signals=true do-timestamp=true is-live=true blocksize=4608000 max-bytes=0 caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=800 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=1920,height=800 ! vtenc_h264 ! avdec_h264 ! autovideosink
```

If anyone has any suggestions for how I can fix this problem I would appreciate it. I'm hoping it's a simple change but you never know with gstreamer!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment, and this can solve your problem if I am correct..

Add queue before filesink:

```
appsrc format=3 name=app emit-signals=true do-timestamp=true is-live=true blocksize=4608000 max-bytes=0 caps=video/x-raw,format=BGR,width=1920,height=800 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=I420,width=1920,height=800 ! queue ! vtenc_h264 ! mp4mux ! queue ! filesink location=test1.mp4
```

Queue has two functions:
+ make a buffer before consuming element (which encoder is - it needs many frames before it can start encoding)
+ separate further processing into new thread - so that filesink would process data in new thread.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the quick response @otoplsky! Unfortunately adding those two queues didn't solve the problem. One process immediately begins writing to file while and the other stays at 0MB. I did get a new error message from adding the queues that only fires once in the very beginning:
ERROR: GST_PADS gstpad.c:3279:gboolean gst_pad_query_latency_default(GstPad *, GstQuery *):<mp4mux0:src> minimum latency bigger than maximum latency.

I also always get the following error on launch:
vtenc vtenc.c:807:gst_vtenc_create_session:<vtenc_h264-0> VTCompressionSessionCreate() returned: -12915